# Java count the vowels program

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that lets the user input a word, then it will count the number of vowels and consonants in that word and print the amount. e.g: The word 'YOURWORD' contains 3 vowels and 5 consonants.

Since a consonant is just each letter that isn't a vowel, I only made the program check if there was a vowel in the word and then the number of consonants is just the number of other letters in the word. However, I'm struggling with the for loop. Here is my code:

```
   String word;
    Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a word.");
    word = myinput.next();
    char[] wordc = word.toCharArray();

    for(int w = 0;w > word.length();w++;) {
      if(wordc[w] == 'a' || wordc[w] == 'e' || wordc[w] == 'i' || wordc[w] == 'o' || wordc[w] == 'u') {

      }
```

As you can see, I'm so close to the end but I literally have no clue what to do now. I'm a beginner at Java and I have checked the for loop syntax but I really don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: That's an infinite loop. Should be `w < word.length()`.

Comment: ^ To clarify; technically its not an infinite loop, its a loop who's conditional is never met, thus never executes.  But, does have the potential to be an infinite loop if w was instantiated to be something greater than word.length() and needs to be changed.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
for(int w = 0;w > word.length();w++)
```

to

```
for(int w = 0;w < word.length();w++)
```

because when you set `w` to 0, obviously, your `word.length()` is greater than 0, which makes the condition in the `for` loop false. Hence, the `for` loop would be **not** be executed even *once*.

To count the number of vowels, you define one more integer outside the `for` loop and increment it as you encounter a vowel. So, your code should look like:

```
String word;
Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a word.");
word = myinput.next();
//Convert your string to lowercase using toLowerCase() method.
char[] wordc = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
int vowels = 0; //This counter will count the vowels.
for(int w = 0;w < word.length();w++) {
  if(wordc[w] == 'a' || wordc[w] == 'e' || wordc[w] == 'i' || wordc[w] == 'o' || wordc[w] == 'u') {
      vowels++;
  }
}
int consonants = word.length() - vowels; 
//Assuming no special characters in your word.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define two int variables to do counting. 
the for loop goes like below

```
   String word;
int numberOfVowls = 0; numberofCosonents = 0;
    Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a word.");
    word = myinput.next();
    char[] wordc = word.toCharArray();

    for(int w = 0;w < word.length();w++;) {
      if(wordc[w] == 'a' || wordc[w] == 'e' || wordc[w] == 'i' || wordc[w] == 'o' || wordc[w] == 'u') numberOfVowls++;
else numberofCosonents++;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String word;
Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter a word.");
word = myinput.next();
char[] wordc = word.toCharArray();

int vowels = 0;

for (char w: wordc) {
    if(w == 'a' || w == 'e' || w == 'i' || w == 'o' || w == 'u') {
        vowels++;
    }
}

System.out.println("Number of vowels in " + word + " is: " + vowels);
System.out.println("Number of consonants in " + word + " is: " + (wordc.length - vowels));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to count vowels and consonants without using loops and multiple conditions.

```
String word = "YOURWORD"; // assuming only letters

String vowels = word.replaceAll( "(?i)[^aeiou]+", "" ); // OUO

int numVowels     = vowels.length(); // 3
int numConsonants = word.length() - numVowels; // 5
```

**How it works:**

In the `word.replaceAll( "(?i)[^aeiou]+", "" )` call we are replacing everything that is not one of `[^aeiou]` thus leaving only vowels in returned string.

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] arr = text.split(" ");
     char elementch = ' ';

     //looping through string array
    for(int i=1; i<= arr.length ; i++){
        String nextElement = arr[i-1];

        int add = 0;
            //looping through each character in the next element
            for (char ch: nextElement.toCharArray()) {
                //checking if ch == to vowels
                if(ch == 'e'|| ch == 'a' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u'|| ch == 'i'){
                    //add counts number of vowels for every string array index
                    add = add +1;
                    elementch = ch; 
                    System.out.print(" ' " +elementch + " ' ");
                }else{
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The number of vowels is "+ add + " in" + " : " + nextElement.toUpperCase());
    }
```